# Force a Sympy expression to contain a symbol

Tags: python, sympy, symbols, solver

I wrote the following code in python3 (with the intention to compute then draw [nullclines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullcline) of a 2-D dynamic system):

```
import sympy as sm
x1, x2 = sm.symbols('x1 x2')
x = [x1, x2]
sys = sm.Matrix([(x1 - sm.log(x2))*(x2-x1*x1),
    x2**2 - 4])
solutions = list(map(lambda dx: sm.solve(sm.Eq(dx, 0)), sys))
print(solutions)
```

What I see is

```
 [[{x1: -sqrt(x2)}, {x1: sqrt(x2)}, {x1: log(x2)}], [-2, 2]]
```

This [-2,2] gives me a big problem, as I want to draw the solutions next. Since I want to work with `sys` whether or not each element contains both variables. I'd like to iterate over the dictionaries and plot `sm.Eq(list(solutions[i][j].keys())[0], list(solutions[i][j].values())[0])` but I can't guarantee a dictionary like this

I saw that if I add `+ x1 - sm.log(sm.exp(x1))` to `sys[1]` it will give me the consistent dictionary form, but is there a way for me to force `sys`' element to contain both in a more elegant way? I don't want to look in each element for both coordinates and if one isn't present to add the redundant expression to it

Comment: `list(map(lambda dx: sm.solve(sm.Eq(dx, 0)), sys))` is equivalent to `[sm.solve(sm.Eq(dx, 0)) for dx in sys]`. You are not solving a system of equations, you are solving two equations. Sorry, if this is obvious to you, I imagine solving a system of equations when drawing nullclines, but I may misunderstand your goal.

Comment: It does look more elegant, but it still doesn't help me with the problem, where for some systems one equation is independent on a coordinate and `solve()`'s output is not in a dictionary form

Comment: sys is a frequently used module. best not to use it as a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `dict=True` does that. With `sm.solve(sm.Eq(dx, 0), dict=True)` the output of your code is

```
[[{x1: -sqrt(x2)}, {x1: sqrt(x2)}, {x1: log(x2)}], [{x2: -2}, {x2: 2}]]
```

That said, I'm not sure that you win anything versus using simply [`plot_implicit`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) directly on the equations in `sys`. Consider that the different solutions you get will have different domains of definition, as the curves turn around or go sideways (parabolas, etc). Going to be a headache to plot all those pieces.

Here is how it works with `plot_implicit`

```
import sympy as sm
x1, x2 = sm.symbols('x1 x2')
eqs = [(x1 - sm.log(x2))*(x2-x1*x1), x2**2 - 4]
window = [(x1, -3, 3), (x2, -3, 3)]
plots = [plot_implicit(eq, *window, show=False) for eq in eqs]
combined_plots = plots[0]
for k in range(1, len(plots)):
  combined_plots.extend(plots[k])
combined_plots.show()
```

[image: nullclines]

Comment: Oh wow! That's exactly what I needed. I didn't know a bunch of the convenient sympy features here